# Rails - filter using join model on has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

How do I add filter on Place table for Facility that is link has_many through relationship?

This is how all models look like:

```
class Place < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :facilities, through: :place_facilities
  has_many :place_facilities, dependent: :destroy

class PlaceFacility < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :place
  belongs_to :facility
end

class Facility < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :places, through: :place_facilities
  has_many :place_facilities
end
```

I want user to able filter places that has specific facilities.

Comment: What are different columns the Facility model has?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Place.includes(:facilities).where(facilities: { attribute: "specific" })
```

For more info, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations

Comment: a verbal explanation is often helpful

Comment: I've added a link to the official documentation.

Comment: @NovaTogatorop Can you upvote / mark it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty easy using `joins` and `where`

```
my_places = Place.joins(:facility).where(facilities: {name: 'blackboard'})
```